# Fetch Facebook friends list using java code

Tags: facebook-java-api

is it possible to get facebook friends list without having the facebook api key user

can you explain

thank you

Answer (score 1):

No.  The user needs to approve your application which returns an access token before you can get any information about the user, including their friend list.